# Exceptions when creating Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently deleted my user account on my PC and restored the data to a new account on the same PC. And since I am facing problems while creating an Android Studio project outside of the folder C:\Users\John\AndroidStudioProjects (Supposing John is my user name and AndroidStudioProjects is a folder that I created). So when creating a project in C:\Users\John\Documents\Folder it will create some exceptions being unable to successfully run Gradle.
The exceptions are:

```
   org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not
   create service of type FileHasher using
   BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().
   org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
   java.io.IOException: Access is denied
```

I tried to delete Android Studio, or run an old project in these folders, nothing worked
Only projects in `C:\Users\John\AndroidStudioProjects` works

Please help me 
Thank you

Comment: Did you try to install android studio again?

Comment: Yes, not effective

Answer (score 0):

Try running android studio as administrator. If you can use other Directorys as Administrator, check what user owns the /AndroidStudioProjects/ and what user is owning the other Folders

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: Also if I create any folder directly in the user's folder it will work, but in system's folders like Documents it's not working

Comment: this seems to be a privilege issue